# Unable to install the Visual Studio Installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

[image: Screenshot of fail]

I have tried to repair Windows Management Instrumentation service, but everything I see and do indicates that it is working fine. 4 hours of googling has not helped; any ideas?

Here's a log file from a folder the install created:

https://pastebin.com/9kTFPiqh

```
Small code section to make psstebin work
```

Comment: There are command line options (use `-?` to see the commands) to save a log from the install. Do that and include a link to it in your question. You can put the content of it on pastebin.com

Comment: Log file added.

Comment: [This link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bae90cfd-702d-427f-a4df-c66cc8c4d56d/sql-express-2008-installation-error?forum=sqlexpress) might be useful.

Comment: Very promising, but it didn't help. I did notice when I checked the WMI service that it has no service dependencies (it depends on no services, and no services depend on it). Then I checked some other services, and none of them had any dependencies either. Beginning to think its time to wipe windows...